Is it possible for two processes to deadlock on blocking send()/receive() calls due to both receive buffers being full?
Assume we have two clients talking to each other over TCP.  Both are doing roughly the same thing:
recv(...) // Blocking receive call
do_work()
send(...) // Blocking send other client.

The way the TCP protocol is specified, is it possible for this to deadlock?  For example, if we have two clients 'A' and 'B', if A's receive buffer is full while sending a message to B, meanwhile B's receive buffer is full while attempting to send to 'A', is there anything in the TCP protocol that prevents a deadlock here?
Assuming there is nothing in the protocol here to prevent a deadlock, do common implementations (for example, Linux's socket API) have some mechanism to prevent this for blocking calls?

If they are both sending to each other at the same time, and both have full buffers, and neither is reading, then yes, this can deadlock if you don't put a timeout on the sends. But, why are you not simply reading in a separate thread, or using non-blocking reads/sends, to avoid having full buffers in the first place?

I think the mechanism to prevent the problem is to call setsockopt(SO_SNDBUF) to make your socket's send-buffer large enough that you can send all the data you need without blocking.  But I agree with Remy that a better solution is to avoid blocking I/O in the first place, as blocking I/O means that your program must rely on an external process to send all the expected data, or else it will block forever... not a recipe for robustness.

Not sure what you expect instead of blocking when it cannot write more data to the socket buffer since the peer does not read it. One obvious option is that the send would fail. But this is exact the behavior you have with non-blocking sockets: succeed if it can write to the socket buffer and fail if the buffer is full and thus the send cannot succeed without blocking (errno EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK)

TCP is a reliable protocol which guarantees data delivery to the peer.
If the application is not reading any data from the socket, any arriving data must either be put into some read socket buffer in the receiver until the application reads it, or the data will dropped but then can also not be acknowledged (reliability properties of TCP).
Since memory is limited the receiving system cannot endlessly read new data into the socket buffer if the application does not read it. It will signal this problem to the sender through TCP window updates but if the sender does not stop sending, then the recipient will have no choice to simply discard incoming data and not acknowledge these.
In this situation the sender faces a similar problem in that it must somhow buffer any data the local applications sends but which cannot be delivered to the peer. Since memory is limited on the sender side too ultimatively a blocking send in the application MUST block.
Of course, neither sender and recipient will allow to exhaust all system memory. They simply have an upper limit of the size of each socket buffer, so  blocking the send can happen fairly quickly.
And if both application block on send and neither does anything in parallel to solve the peers blocking send by reading data, then one has a dead-lock.
There is nothing TCP or the OS could conceptionally do to mitigate this on a blocking socket within the constraints of a) TCP is reliable and b) systems have limited memory. Of course, with a non-blocking socket it is easy - just don't block but fail the operation.

I know you are not an AI, but this really feels like an AI-generated answer.

@RemyLebeau:  Funny thought. But you are right, there is nothing exciting or special about this answer, it is just boringly stating one kind of obvious thing after the other to finally come up with a conclusion. It might be because the question is not actually complex and so I could answer it with system 1 thinking only, w/o the need for deeper thoughts :)  Tried to put this in MS copilot and the answer I got was fairly good at the beginning - but then a  bit too much elaborating about things not actually asked for.
